# How to add icon to springboard

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I have a question about add icon to springboard. In Mobile Safari, you can add a website to springboard as an icon.  Then you can click the icon to enter this website. So, I wonder if there is an method to add such icon to springboard by program. Whether or not jailbreak is not matter. Thanks.

Comment: what do you want the icon to do?  launch your own custom app?  something else?  please clarify.